# Integrating CKEditor with Aurelia

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aurelia

I'm working on a SPA that needs a WYSIWYG Editor. For this I've decided to use CKEditor with aurelia, aurelia-cli, npm, and typescript.

I've installed `npm install ckeditor --save`

and also in my aurelia.json file, I've added the ckeditor npm package as a dependency.

```
"dependencies": [
      {
        "name": "ckeditor",
        "path": "../node_modules/ckeditor",
        "main": "ckeditor",
        "resources": [
          "config.js",
          "skins/moono-lisa/editor.css",
          "lang/en.js"
        ]
      }
]
```

I've also added the ckeditor.d.ts typings definition to my custom_typings folder. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/ckeditor

At this point, when I refresh the page, I get the following errors:

Any help would be much appreciated :)

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined
    at vendor-bundle.js:36119
(anonymous) @ vendor-bundle.js:36119
vendor-bundle.js:11929 DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin aurelia-templating-binding.
vendor-bundle.js:11929 DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin aurelia-templating-binding.
vendor-bundle.js:11929 DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin aurelia-templating-resources.
vendor-bundle.js:11929 DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin aurelia-templating-resources.
vendor-bundle.js:11929 DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin aurelia-event-aggregator.
vendor-bundle.js:11929 DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin aurelia-event-aggregator.
vendor-bundle.js:11929 DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin aurelia-history-browser.
vendor-bundle.js:11929 DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin aurelia-history-browser.
vendor-bundle.js:11929 DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin aurelia-templating-router.
vendor-bundle.js:11929 DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin aurelia-templating-router.
vendor-bundle.js:11929 DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin resources/index.
vendor-bundle.js:11929 DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin resources/index.
vendor-bundle.js:11929 DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin aurelia-dialog.
vendor-bundle.js:11929 DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin aurelia-dialog.
vendor-bundle.js:11929 DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin aurelia-testing.
vendor-bundle.js:11929 DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin aurelia-testing.
vendor-bundle.js:11929 DEBUG [templating] importing resources for aurelia-templating-resources/compose []
vendor-bundle.js:11929 DEBUG [templating] importing resources for aurelia-templating-router/router-view []
vendor-bundle.js:11929 DEBUG [templating] importing resources for resources/elements/label-input.html []
vendor-bundle.js:11929 DEBUG [templating] importing resources for resources/elements/label-select.html []
vendor-bundle.js:11939 INFO [aurelia] Aurelia Started
vendor-bundle.js:11929 DEBUG [templating] importing resources for app.html []
vendor-bundle.js:11929 DEBUG [templating] importing resources for resources/dialogs/wysiwyg-editor-dialog.html ["resources/elements/wysiwyg-editor"]
vendor-bundle.js:3790 GET http://localhost/viewer_editor/node_modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.js 
vendor-bundle.js:1399 Unhandled rejection Error: Script error for "ckeditor/ckeditor", needed by: resources/elements/wysiwyg-editor
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at F (http://localhost/app/263/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:3763:290)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (http://localhost/app/263/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:3786:113)
From previous event:
    at DefaultLoader.loadModule (http://localhost/app/263/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:11807:14)
    at DefaultLoader.loadAllModules (http://localhost/app/263/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:11754:25)
    at ViewEngine.importViewResources (http://localhost/app/263/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:19396:26)
    at ViewEngine.loadTemplateResources (http://localhost/app/263/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:19366:19)
    at http://localhost/app/263/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:19314:41
From previous event:
    at ViewEngine.loadViewFactory (http://localhost/app/263/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:19298:67)
    at ConventionalViewStrategy.loadViewFactory (http://localhost/app/263/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:16718:25)
    at HtmlBehaviorResource.load (http://localhost/app/263/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:20056:29)
    at http://localhost/app/263/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:20589:18
From previous event:
    at CompositionEngine.createController (http://localhost/app/263/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:20577:71)
    at CompositionEngine._createControllerAndSwap (http://localhost/app/263/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:20556:19)
    at CompositionEngine.compose (http://localhost/app/263/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:20636:21)
    at http://localhost/app/scripts/app-bundle.js:4618:44
From previous event:
    at http://localhost/app/scripts/app-bundle.js:4613:122
From previous event:
    at _openDialog (http://localhost/app/scripts/app-bundle.js:4609:66)
    at http://localhost/app/scripts/app-bundle.js:4555:16
From previous event:
    at DialogService.open (http://localhost/app/scripts/app-bundle.js:4551:21)
    at CommonDialogs.showWysiwygEditorDialog (http://localhost/app/scripts/app-bundle.js:1375:39)
    at Scene.openWysiwygEditorDialog (http://localhost/app/scripts/app-bundle.js:3591:32)
    at CallScope.evaluate (http://localhost/app/263/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:6658:21)
    at Listener.callSource (http://localhost/app/263/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:10100:42)
    at http://localhost/app/263/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:10124:24
    at HTMLDocument.handleDelegatedEvent (http://localhost/app/263/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:8303:11)
printWarning @ vendor-bundle.js:1399
formatAndLogError @ vendor-bundle.js:1115
fireRejectionEvent @ vendor-bundle.js:1140
Promise._notifyUnhandledRejection @ vendor-bundle.js:587
(anonymous) @ vendor-bundle.js:132
```

Comment: CKEditor is best used being loaded via a script tag. We use this strategy in our "Intermediate Aurelia" workshop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must import CKEditor's scripts in your code. Like this:

```
import 'ckeditor';
```

This is an example of custom-element that generates a CKEditor.

**editor.js**

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-templating';
import {bindingMode} from 'aurelia-binding';
import {DOM} from 'aurelia-pal';
import 'ckeditor';

@inject(DOM.Element)
export class Editor {
  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) value;
  @bindable name;

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  updateValue() {
    this.value = this.textArea.value;
  }

  bind() {
    this.textArea = this.element.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
    let editor = CKEDITOR.replace(this.textArea);
    editor.on('change', (e) => {
      this.value = e.editor.getData();
    });
  }
}
```

**editor.html**

```
<template>
  <textarea change.delegate="updateValue()"></textarea>
  <input type="hidden" name.bind="name" value.bind="value">
</template>
```

To make this work in production, you will have to export some ckeditor static files, *config.js, styles.css, content.css, etc*. Unfortunately, there's no way to do this in CLI *right now* (I've made a PR to add this feature https://github.com/aurelia/cli/pull/415). So, you'd have to create a gulp task to export these files when building the app.

Answer (score 0):

in Aurelia.json under "copyFiles" include the following:

"node_modules/ckeditor/*": "wwwroot/ckeditor",
  "node_modules/ckeditor/skins/moono-lisa/*": "wwwroot/ckeditor/skins/moono-lisa",
  "node_modules/ckeditor/skins/moono-lisa/images/*": "wwwroot/ckeditor/skins/moono-lisa/images",
  "node_modules/ckeditor/lang/*": "wwwroot/ckeditor/lang",
  "node_modules/ckeditor/plugins/*": "wwwroot/ckeditor/plugins",
  "node_modules/ckeditor/plugins/scayt/skins/moono-lisa/*": "wwwroot/ckeditor/plugins/scayt/skins/moono-lisa",
  "node_modules/ckeditor/plugins/scayt/dialogs/*": "wwwroot/ckeditor/plugins/scayt/dialogs",
  "node_modules/ckeditor/plugins/tableselection/styles/*": "wwwroot/ckeditor/plugins/tableselection/styles",
  "node_modules/ckeditor/plugins/wsc/dialogs/*": "wwwroot/ckeditor/plugins/wsc/dialogs",
  "node_modules/ckeditor/plugins/wsc/skins/moono-lisa/*": "wwwroot/ckeditor/plugins/wsc/skins/moono-lisa"